# Pygame, screen only updates when exiting pygame window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.3

I'm fairly new to pygame and i needed some help because my code is not working properly.

Okay so here's the problem: I want the screen to turn white when i run it but it remains black, however when i press the exit, it turns white for about a second and then closes.

This also happens when i put a picture (like the player.png) it appears for about a second before exiting. I don't know what i'm doing wrong,

please help fix the code and explain why it is happening?

here is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
image = pygame.image.load('player.png')
gameExit = False
gameLoop = True

pygame.display.update()
white = (255,255,255)

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        gameExit = True

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        screen.fill(white)







pygame.display.update()




pygame.quit()
quit()
```

PS. I don't get any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is indentation sensitive. In your code, you call `pygame.display.update()` only once your main loop ends.

Also, you only paint the background white in the case there's an event in the event queue between the two `for` loops, and then you fill the background for every event in the queue.

Note that this could also lead to a situation in which your `QUIT` event is "swallowed" by the second loop.

---

So this

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        gameExit = True

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        screen.fill(white)

pygame.display.update()
```

should be

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True

    screen.fill(white)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :), I really appreciate that you explained it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I agree with Sloth, but instead of doing all the screen updating and filling and blitting at the end, making the script less readable, you should make like an `animate` function that runs at the end of the while loop each time, and put the blitting and screen updating stuff in that function. Sorry for the run-on sentence.

Oh and you don't need your `GameLoop` variable.